# why doesn't `find . -name '*.jar' | xargs jar tf` work?

Tags: xargs, jar

I ran this

`find . -name '*.jar' | xargs jar tf`

hoping it would, find all the `.jar` files and execute `jar tf` on them (to view the content).
But it didn't seem to work!!!

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: It just returns nothing ... (prints nothing to the console)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `xargs` and `jar tf` the wrong way.

The original purpose of `xargs` is to pass *as many files as it can* at once – so you end up with a few `jar tf file1 file2 file3 file4 ... file200 ...` invocations.

But `jar t`, much like `tar t`, only accepts *one* .jar file at once. All remaining arguments act as *filters* for what to list/extract. For example, `jar tf thing.jar org/example` would only list files from the "org/example" subdirectory.

So if you run `jar tf file1.jar file2.jar file3.jar`, it only reads *file1.jar*, and expects the rest to match files *within* the archive.

So instead you need to tell `xargs` to run the command *once per file*:

```
find ... | xargs -d '\n' -n 1 jar tf
```

(The `-d '\n'` option has nothing to do with your problem, but it is a good idea nevertheless – just in case you happen to find some files with spaces in their names.)

A more direct way of doing the same is:

```
find ... -exec jar tf {} \;
```

Comment: The `-d` thing is unnecessary because there’s an even better way: use `-print0` on `find` and `-0` with `xargs`.